# Jquery sticky footer that stops 350px before bottom of page content

Tags: jquery, footer, sticky

How would I, with Jquery, make a sticky footer that sticks to the bottom of the browser until it hits 350px before the end of the content. Basically I have another big footer at the bottom of the content and I want the sticky footer to stay sticky until you scroll to the 350px footer and it will stay ontop of the last footer so you can read the content

basically something like make a sticky footer but then 350px before the bottom of wherever the bottom of the content is stop the sticky footer and make it scroll with the page.

I found this online but i know the code to find out where the end of the content, as opposed to the end of the veiwable browser, would be different...Although it does work as a general sticky footer

```
$(function(){
positionFooter(); 
function positionFooter(){
    if($(document).height() < $(window).height()){
        $("#globalFooter").css({position: "absolute",top:($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-$("#globalFooter").height())+"px" - })
    }   
}

$(window)
    .scroll(positionFooter)
    .resize(positionFooter)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written an example to demonstrate how you would go about creating a sticky footer. In the example, the value `bottomBound` would be the height of your other non-sticky footer.

It's important to use a `DOCTYPE` declaration, because `$(window).height()` breaks without it.

The code is here: [GitHub - stickyFooter](https://github.com/emmerich/stickyNav/blob/master/demo/stickyFooter.html) and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PBn8q/5/).

For those interested in doing this with a header rather than a footer, there's also examples of that here: [GitHub - stickyNav](https://github.com/emmerich/stickyNav)

Edit: Restructured answer.

Comment: that actually works pretty well. Although im not that great at JS so I couldn't really implement it how I need. Check this out I almost got it but sort of in the reverse way I need it...Right now it starts at 350px above the bottom then goes to the bottom and stays there...it pretty much needs to be reversed, any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/PBn8q/1/

Comment: Hey Mike. I adapted my code and took another stab at it. Check my edit for the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ZVzEe/

```
var secondary = $("#secondary-footer");

secondary.hide().addClass("fixed").fadeIn("fast");

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (secondary.offset().top >= ($(document).height() - 350)) {
        secondary.removeClass("fixed");
    }
    else if(secondary + ":not('.fixed')") {
        secondary.addClass("fixed");
    }
});​
```

Comment: hey that works great, only thing is when you scroll to the bottom, the sticky footer goes to the top but then the scroll on the page jumps up a bit too, then if you scroll down more it breaks...any thoughts? OTher than that it works exactly how I was saying!!